# Find the angle $x$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, soft-question, triangles

[image]

I have been trying this, but got no an answer. Any ideas please.

Comment: Can't you  put a legend  or annotation or name the vertices on your figure to simply the workload?

Comment: Hint: All inner angles of a triangle sum up to $180°$.

Comment: @Angelo Mark By law of sines I got $45^{\circ}$. Now you can find a nice solution.

Comment: yes but that hint does nont provide any improvement

Answer (score 2):

By law of sines I got $$x=180^{\circ}-70^{\circ}-35^{\circ}-\arctan\frac{\sin115^{\circ}\sin25^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}}{\sin30^{\circ}\sin75^{\circ}+\sin25^{\circ}\sin35^{\circ}\cos115^{\circ}}=45^{\circ}$$ Now you can find a nice solution.

Comment: Can you show me your steps please